# How to import session key(RSA public key exchange) in UWP

Tags: uwp, cryptography

I need implement a decrypto function like these in win32, but I do know how to import the session key in UWP.

```
CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, L"DecryptContainer", MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET) ; 

// private key blob in pbPrvBlob
BYTE *pbPrvBlob;
DWORD cbPrvBlob; 

// Convert the private key file bytes into an HCRYPTKEY.

HCRYPTKEY hKey;
hr = CryptImportKey(hProv, pbPrvBlob, cbPrvBlob, 0, 0, &hKey);

// Convert the encrypted session key file bytes into an HCRYPTKEY.
BYTE *pbSymBlob; // contain encrypted session key blob
DWORD cbSymBlob;
HCRYPTKEY hSymKey;
CryptImportKey(hProv, pbSymBlob, cbSymBlob, hKey, 0, &hSymKey);
```

I Try this code in UWP, the APIs do not support RSA public key exchange algorithm blob file. So I get the encrypted data and try to decrypt with RSA privite key. Failed in the decrypt function. How do we import the RSA public key exchange algorithm blob file?

```
void test_load_keys()
{
    byte[] PrvBlob = await ReadFileToByteArray("prvkey.blob");
    byte[] Cipher = await ReadFileToByteArray("userdata.blob");
    byte[] SymBlob = await ReadFileToByteArray("sessionkey.blob");

    IBuffer PrvBlobBuffer = PrvBlob.AsBuffer();
    AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider asymmAlg = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);

    CryptographicKey Prvkey = asymmAlg.ImportKeyPair(PrvBlobBuffer, CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Capi1PrivateKey);

    IBuffer sessionblob = SymBlob.AsBuffer();
    int offset_start = 12;
    int encryed_length = 128;
    int count = (SymBlob.Length - offset_start) / encryed_length;

    IBuffer EnSessionKey = SymBlob.AsBuffer(offset_start, encryed_length);
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(EnSessionKey.ToArray()));
    // Failed nex line with "Value does not fall within the expected range"  
    IBuffer keydeBlobSlic = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(Prvkey, EnSessionKey, null); 
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(keydeBlobSlic.ToArray()));


    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider symAlg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc);
    CryptographicKey key = symAlg.CreateSymmetricKey(keydeBlobSlic);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I cannot be sure whether you want to use C# or C++ in UWP when coding. But have you got a chance to see this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider#examples) it's the way how UWP app can work with session key.

Comment: Where the API AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provide a way for you to import public key or public key pair

Comment: I found UWP API can load private key and public key blob file. But I can not use it to import the seesion key blob data, which foramt is RSA public key exchange algorithm. I import RSA private key and try to decry the blob encryed part. The decry function always failed.

Comment: Can you give Xavier's answer from this thread a test https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021389/asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider-import I want to see whether you can use the followed code to generate the right key out:  IBuffer buffer = WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.AsBuffer(data, 0, data.Length);